# vue.js router help what error could mean in console router-link router-view vue.js

Tags: vue.js, console, router

Hi im working on the blog-app to practice vue.js. I have now made it so my nav-bar is showing but I have a problem with the routing.
Here is the errors in the console and the directories and files.

[image: error in console]

**here is my main.js;**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './routers'

import navBar from './components/navbar/navBar.vue';

const app = createApp(App)


app.component('app-navbar', navBar)
app.mount('#app')
app.use(router)
```

**here is my app.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
      <app-navbar></app-navbar>
      <div>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  
}
</script>
```

**here is my routers.js;**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
    {
        name: 'homePosts',
        component: () => import ('./views/homePosts'),
        path: '/homePosts'
    },
    {
        name: 'writePost',
        component: () => import('./views/writePost'),
        path: '/writePost'
    }
];
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
})
export default router
```

**here is my writePost.vue;**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form class="form">
            <label for="">Writer name: </label>
            <input type="text" max="500">
            <br>
            <label for="img">Select image:</label>
            <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
            <br>
            <label for="">Your blogtext: </label>
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="30"></textarea>

        </form> 
    </div>
</template>
<script>
```

**Here is my directories;**

**here is navbar.vue**

```
 <template>
       <div class="container">
        <div>
          <img class="img" src="@/assets/bloglogo.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-div">
            <navbar class="nav">
                    <ul class="navbar">
                        <div class="li"><router-link to="/views/homePosts">Home</router-link></div>
                        <div class="li"><router-link to="/views/writePost">Write a post</router-link></div>
                    </ul>
            </navbar>
        </div>   
      </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you forgot to download the **vue-router** package or I don't know. Because as soon as I run the project, I got the error "*Vue-router module not found*".

To install the **vue-router** package:

```
pnpm install vue-router@latest
```

or

```
npm install vue-router@latest
```

Then I examined your **router.js** file. You should only import and use `.vue` files as components.

**router.js**

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const routes = [
  {
    name: "Home",
    path: "/",
    redirect: { name: "homePosts" },
  },
  {
    name: "homePosts",
    component: () => import("./views/homePosts.vue"),
    path: "/home-posts",
  },
  {
    name: "writePost",
    component: () => import("./views/writePost.vue"),
    path: "/write-post",
  },
];
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});
export default router;
```

When I came to the `/` path, I directed it to the `/home-posts` path. However, if you want, you can create a new component and assign it to `/` path.

Also, I suggest you give your path names as **kebab-case**. Like `/home-posts`

And finally I edited your main.js file a bit.

**main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./routers";

import navBar from "./components/navbar/NavBar.vue";

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.component("app-navbar", navBar);
app.mount("#app");
```

When you follow these steps, your problem should be completely resolved.

Also, as I said in the comment, there is only 1 warning message left, unfortunately I do not know the solution for it.

Comment: thank you but no then it came even more errors and the navbar dissipeared

Comment: VueJS needs to recognize your router because your navbar component uses <router-link></router-link>. Can you try the way I edited?

Comment: Then i get this error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'options' of '(0 , vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.inject)(...)' as it is undefined.
    at setup (vue-router.esm-bundler.js?2d1e:2147:1)
 so on.. and the navbar dissapear

Comment: You did not add `.vue` while importing the components in your router.js file. Can you add and try? I think it may not be able to find the files.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I did the changes but stil same error.

Comment: Can you share your codes on Codesandbox or something else? So I can test directly on your codes.

Comment: Ill give you the github later this evening thank you

Comment: here is my git  https://github.com/Astborg/blogpost1

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. I was trying to finish my own work. I have solved your problem, if nothing goes wrong, I will share it with you in 3-4 hours at the latest, I will explain it in detail. There is only 1 warning message left, and I could not investigate it in detail at the moment. I hope to be able to solve it too :)

Comment: I've edited this answer now. I believe your problem will be solved if you follow the steps in the answer.